# Backbone: How to bind arguments for listenTo-callback?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is it possible to bind function arguments for listenTo callback?

I've till now added a wrapper methods 'myHandler' which I would like to get rid of:

```
// Basic marionette layout
var view = Marionette.Layout.extend({

initialize: function() {
    // wrapping view logic inside a custom object
    this.controller = new MyViewController(); 
},

// creates a sub view and adds event handlers
someFunc: function() {
    var subView = new MySubView();

    // HERE: how to bind args for callback?
    this.listenTo(subView, "myEvent", this.myHandler, this);
}, 

// this is a dummy wrapper that I want to remove
myHandler: function(e) {
    this.controller.handleIt(this, e);
},
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
someFunc: function() {
    var subView = new MySubView();

    // here wrapIt binds 'this' as first argument for handleIt
    this.listenTo(subView, "myEvent",
        wrapIt(this.controller.handleIt, this), this);
}
```

Comment: What's `this.controller.handleIt`?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy it's a FSM for wrapping view logic: [javascript-state-machine](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine)

Comment: Are any of these answers helpful?

Answer (score 7):

`listenTo` is accepting only 3 arguments. If you need to bind function to some object then cross-browser way to do this is using underscore `_.bind` function:

```
this.listenTo(subView, "myEvent", _.bind(this.myHandler, this))
```

However it's mostly not needed as object you are calling `listenTo` on is the default context. To read more see these github issues:

- https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1946
- https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2015

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a function in your listenTo function call? Like so:

```
// Basic marionette layout
var view = Marionette.Layout.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    // wrapping view logic inside a custom object
    this.controller = new MyViewController(); 
  },

  // creates a sub view and adds event handlers
  someFunc: function() {
    var subView = new MySubView();

    this.listenTo(subView, "myEvent", function (e) {
      this.controller.handleIt(this, e);
    }, this);
  },
```

Comment: This is an obsolete solution, 4th argument to listenTo method was removed from backbone core: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2015  you may use _.bind() instead

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is a hard dependency for Backbone which means you can use [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to set the context:

> **bind** _.bind(function, object, [*arguments])
>   Bind a function to an object, meaning that whenever the function is called, the value of
>   this will be the object. Optionally, pass arguments to the function to
>   pre-fill them, also known as partial application.

Your example could be written as

```
someFunc: function() {
    var subView = new MySubView(),
        callback = _.bind(this.controller.handleIt, this);

    this.listenTo(subView, "myEvent", callback, this);
}
```

If you want the context as the first argument to your function, add it as a third argument to `_.bind`

```
someFunc: function() {
    var subView = new MySubView(),
        callback = _.bind(this.controller.handleIt, this, this);

    this.listenTo(subView, "myEvent", callback, this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using proxy function in JQuery
$.proxy( this.controller.handler, this )
See documentation here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/